# Bootcamp/VM Windows 10 licensing

Tags: bootcamp, windows, vmware, parallels-desktop

In the past if I wanted to install Windows on Bootcamp, and then also use Parallels/VMware to open up the Bootcamp installation as a VM I would need two separate Windows licenses. Is this still the case with Windows 10?

Comment: I have Win7 on Bootcamp & as a VM too - I never needed a second license; though I set it up so long ago that memory is hazy as to how I did it.

Comment: From memory, if you opened up the Bootcamp installation in a VM, Windows would detect it was being used on different hardware and then after 100 or so days the VM would go into 'unactivated' mode. This is ages ago though so maybe It doesn't apply anymore?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't recall, it's too long ago. I definitely never had to ring MS to get it activated though, & I only own one key.